# How do I make vite ignore a directory?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

I have a directory `service-worker` at the very top level of my project, that contains one file.

```
$ ls service-worker/
helpers.ts  service-worker.ts
```

I wish to make [vite ignore this directory](https://dev.to/abarke/comment/1n0i7), and have researched [this discussion (which turned out to be an unrelated cause)](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/854) and the [optimizeDeps.exclude()](https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html#optimizedeps-exclude) function.

I am using a minimal `vite.config.ts`:

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["service-worker/*"],
  },
});
```

But the service-worker is always built:

```
$ rm dist/service-worker.js; npx vite build; ls -la dist/service-worker.js

vite v3.0.9 building for production...
✓ 3 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                 0.38 KiB
dist/assets/index.891d93e6.js   0.69 KiB / gzip: 0.39 KiB
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike 1544 Dec 12 19:46 dist/service-worker.js
```

**How do I make vite ignore a directory?**

Comment: any luck figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an **exact** answer to your question, but another way that you could probably achieve the wanted result:*

You can prevent modules from ending up in the bundle, through the rollup option `external`. For example, if I have an import from `@fontsource/roboto-condensed` in any module used in my build, I can exlude the dependency on it like this:

```js
build: {
  rollupOptions: {
    external: ['@fontsource/roboto-condensed'],
  },
},
```

This is a valid way to exclude both package dependencies, but also dependencies on your own local modules. Docs: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external